# c++/WinRT is slower than csWinRTin?

Tags: c++-winrt, winui-3

I am trying the new Microsoft WinUI 3 stack so I found this demo repository from Microsoft:
https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-3-Demos/tree/master/src/Build2020Demo

where it demonstrates the same app using c++/WinRT and CsWinRT .

but the Cs version runs much fatser than the c++ version.
can someone please elaborate why is that?

[C# result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFM97.png)
[Cpp Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSzVN.png)

Comment: Lots of (short-lived) heap allocated objects is certainly a scenario where a compacting heap can outperform a heap implementation for a programming language  (such as C++) where objects aren't allowed to move in memory. I haven't looked into this. If you are interested, run the code under a profiler.

Comment: Also note that you've set the folder depth to 2 in your C# run, and to 3 for the C++ implementation. Obviously, doing more work is more expensive.

Comment: @IInspectable True a made a mistake with the depth , but even at equal depth the c# version still out perform c++ !!!

Comment: @IInspectable also I reached a conclusion that it is not the standard library's fault as I also made a mockup version using win32 API (FindFistFile() and FindNextFIle()) in a new console standard c++ application and even that is not as performant as c#'s implemntation even though is came very close, with c# winning in arround 5-10 milliseconds.

Comment: @IInspectable I don’t thing it’s heap alloc. WinUI3 is written in C++ and COM memory management

Comment: @lot While it's true that WinUI 3 (and 2) are implemented in C++, and both the C# as well as the C++/WinRT demos call into the exact same code, that's not where the (expensive) heap allocations are happening. That's in the [`ListDirectories`](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-3-Demos/blob/master/src/Build2020Demo/DemoBuildCpp/DemoBuildCpp/DemoBuildCpp/MainWindow.xaml.cpp#L85-L104) implementation. It builds the result by constantly appending to a single `std::string` object, causing uncounted re-allocations along the way. That's easily to worst possible way to go about this, in C++.

Comment: If that wasn't bad already, it also makes sure to (implicitly) have the OS constantly convert between ANSI and Unicode character encodings, and when everything is said and done, it once again goes over the final string contents and converts it from ANSI to UTF-16. That fact that it assumes the ANSI encoding to actually be UTF-8 doesn't help much either. If time permits I'll see if I can turn the C++/WinRT version into something that's actually sane.